# jQuery animates (addsClass) to only one <a> tag instead of all?

Tags: jquery

I have this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CS5Bb/2/

Alls I want to happen is when I hover over an `a` tag it animates adding a bit of padding and a border on the left. It does do this for just the first one (Home) but not for the others which are (as far as I can tell) identical.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here. Like, I'm going to slap my forehead when I find out why. But with the jQuery being only 4 lines wrong I really can't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have multiple ids with the same names ...

Use classes instead

*[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CS5Bb/3/)*

```
<p><a class="nav">Home</a></p>
<p><a class="nav">Résumé</a></p>
<p><a class="nav">Contact Me</a></p>


$('.nav').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('navi');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('navi');
});
```

**EDIT #1**

This js doens't do anything that CSS can't do with :hover selector ...

*[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CS5Bb/7/)*

```
.nav:hover {
    border-left: solid red 3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.nav {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: there's no need for javascript. You can directly use :hover for the transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/SVDae/

Comment: Thanks, I had a complete brain fart about the ids being unique. I'm learning jQuery which was why I wanted to try it in there but this works better anyway. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

ID's are unique, so only the first element will be selected when using the ID, as there should'nt be anymore elements with that exact same ID. Use classes instead or target the parent.

From:

```
$('#nav').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('nav');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('nav');
});
```

To:

```
$('.navbar a').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('nav');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('nav');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CS5Bb/6/)